# How to add a block to a category page?

Tags: posts, categories, filters, pages, block-editor

I've got my wordpress site set up to show various menu pages that will feature the content of a category page. I'm curious, is there any way to add a block to the category page? I have a filter that goes into a block, so essentially I need to be able to assign this filter block to a category page to filter my posts. Are there any plugins, or code changes I could do? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Native support might come in a later phase. Just curious, how does the block code look like? Does it need server rendering? If not, it sounds like the problem is how to add static HTML to a category page and possibly enqueue  related styles/scripts.

Comment: I didn't think of that. I'll have to give it a shot.

Comment: This is not yet possible but will be with full-site editing feature that's coming to Gutenberg.